# How to avoid my wordpress website from being cropped?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created a wordpress theme but I have a problem at mobile phones.
The header is set 100% of the page and the main content is 980px and it is centered.

I need a fix so my header will be at least 20px left and 20px right wider than the main content.

Please see mydr.nl for html/css

**What I need on mobile phones:**
[image]

**What I get on mobile phones:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set a padding of 20 pixel to the left and the right of your wrapper class.

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 980px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```